# Why doesn't Spark RDD support "flatten"

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd, higher-order-functions

Have a look at this snippet [*]:

```
val la = List(Array(2, 3, 5), Array(7, 11, 13))
la.flatten
```

returns

```
res1: List[Int] = List(2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13)
```

Now, I've been playing with Spark and I stumbled upon a problem. The snippet:

```
val myRdd: RDD[String] = sc.textFile("myFilePath", 10) map (_.split("\n"))
```

does not compile as the right hand-side expression is of type `RDD[Array[String]]`

Like in the [*], I thought flattening would do the trick:

```
val myRdd: RDD[String] = (sc.textFile("myFilePath", 10) map (_.split("\n"))).flatten
```

But it turns out that `RDD` does not provide this operation. Here come my questions:

1. What is the (design) reason behind RDD not supporting `flatten`?
2. Am I am missing an important point on how RDDs work/should be used?

P.S.
I do know that I can just use the old good `flatMap` to achieve what I want

```
val myRdd: RDD[String] = (sc.textFile("myFilePath", 10) map (_.split("\n"))).flatMap(x => x)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use flatMap instead of map here.

```
val myRdd: RDD[String] = sc.textFile("myFilePath", 10) flatMap (_.split("\n"))
```

Also textFile will already split the file by line so your split is unnecessary.

Flatten was not implemented because it would be difficult to implement and you can just use `flatMap(identity)` to the same effect. Since it would be redundant anyway it is not worth the effort to implement.  See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-18855.

Comment: Thx! Great remarks. The issue answers my question. Still, I am not convinced, if `flatten` is redundant why does `scala` herself provide it? I think it should be provided since the other higher-order functions are.

Comment: @GA1 Scala collections and spark are made by different teams with different ideas, and  an RDD is quite a bit different from a regular collection.  If you read the related issue and pull request linked you'll see that is has been tried, but according to the devs it would be difficult to implement and they don't think there's any real benefit due flatmap proving the same functionality so they would rather spend resources on something more impactful.